# Where should I post question about how to track changes made to a Windows file systems?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Below is my unabridged question. My meta questions are:

- Where should I post such a question?
- How should it be abbreviated?
- How should the question be worded so as to not violate Stack Exchanges guidelines meant to avoid opinionated discussions and software plugs?
- Does such a question in any form even belong on Stack Exchange? I.e. Perhaps it's too broad.

> The company I am working with is transitioning  from a local network file server (Windows 2008 R2 -- only used to store and serve files accessible to machines within the LAN) to a remotely hosted Windows 7 machine.
>
> The amount of files we are having to migrate to the remote machine is somewhat cumbersome, about 350 GB.
>
> About two weeks ago I cloned all the contents we would like to put on the remote server onto a hard drive and mailed it to the people running the server. They have since put those files on the server and the staff at our office is now trained to begin filing newly received documents onto the Remote machine.
>
> However, between the time that I cloned the local server content and now, a not unconsiderable amount of changes  have been made to our local file server. What are some best practices/tools for syncing those changes to the remote machine?

Comment: [Super User](http://superuser.com)?

Comment: @Machavity "What are some best practices/tools for syncing those changes to the remote machine?" Is An question seeking an opinion.

Comment: I think asking for a list of "best practices" and/or tools would also make this too broad for focussed Q&A.

Answer (score 2):

The last sentence makes the question problematic on any SE site, but fortunately it's not difficult to fix. Just say "How should I synchronize these efficiently?", and give any additional constraints (budget, HIPAA compliance [admittedly not likely], etc), and it should fit reasonably well on Super User as-is. Alternatively, it can be recast as a request for specific software to do the job and put on Software Recommendations; SU answers are more likely to mention existing Windows features that could help without installing any third-party software.